# Issue with delete triggers - SQL Server 2005

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, triggers, dataset

I have two fields, LastModifiedBy and DateLastModified in a SQL table. Using ADO.net, I am modifying these fields and calling AcceptChanges function to commit these changes to the dataset (not to the database). I am then calling the Delete function on the datarow. I then call the Update function on the adapter. Technically, the datarow now has values in the two fields mentioned above and they are committed to the dataset, but the SQL Server delete trigger still shows that the values in these fields is null. How can this be?

Regards,
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

Because of several issues:

- You modify fields and then calling `AcceptChanges` = datasets thinks that these data were saved to database but they didn't!
- You delete the row but deletion doesn't cause changes to be passed to the database. It simply calls delete for the current state of the row in the database.

So you must divide the operation into two steps:

- Modify fields and Update changes to the database - it will write fields to the record
- Delete row and Update changes to the database - it will delete record with already passed fields

Make this in single transaction.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now understand what is actually happening with the delete operation.